# Jupyter notebook and live plotting data gathered by a keithley 2450

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

So I'm running some measurements using a keithley 2450 source meter with this code:

```
def res_trace(n = None, max_v = None, min_v = None, data_points = None, r_crit = None,
             ilim = None):
    
    beep(164,0.5)
    # check values and provide defaults
    n = n or 0
    data_points = data_points or 100
    max_v = max_v or 0.5
    min_v = min_v or -0.5
    r_crit = r_crit or 1e+7
    ilim = ilim or 'MAXimum'
    v = np.linspace( min_v, max_v, num = data_points)
    i = []
    res_run = [] 
    
    # reset keithley 
    # just so we can use them without any prior settings
    reset()

    # set up I measurement systems
    keith.write(':SENSe:FUNCtion "CURR"')
    keith.write(':SENSe:CURRent:RANGe:AUTO 1')
    keith.write(':SENSe:CURRent:UNIT AMP')
    keith.write(':SENSe:CURRent:NPLCycles DEFault')
    keith.write(':SENSe:COUNt DEFault')
    keith.write(':SENSe:CURRent:OCOM ON')
    
    # set up V source, (Hi Michale here!)
    keith.write(':SOURce:FUNCtion VOLT')
    keith.write(':SOURce:VOLTage:RANGe '+str(max_v))
    keith.write(':SOURce:VOLTage:ILIMit '+ ilim)

    # Turn keith on
    keith_output('on')

    for j in v:
    
        keith.write(':SOURce:VOLT '+str(j))
        itemp =  float(keith.query(':MEASure:CURRent?'))
        i.append(itemp)
    ###
    
    # turn them off
    keith_output('off')
    
    # plot
    plt.figure()
    plt.title('Res trace # '+str(n))
    plt.plot(v,i, c = 'm')
    plt.xlabel('V')
    plt.ylabel('I')
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

I'm currently running the script and it takes a few seconds for keithley to take measurements and return values. I'd like to get a way to live plot the data within each loop as its being collected, but I have no idea how to go about this and want the process to be as simple as possible. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Jupyterplot](https://pythonawesome.com/create-real-time-plots-in-jupyter-notebooks/) and create a realtime plot like this:

```
from jupyterplot import ProgressPlot
import numpy as np

pp = ProgressPlot()
for i in range(1000):
    pp.update(np.sin(i / 100))
pp.finalize()
```

Comment: Heheheheheheheheh pp

Comment: Ill try that out, seems quite straight forward. Thanks!